# JavaScript does not work well inside a loaded content in a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating an application with Symfony2, where I have a main menu of options depending on the option selected dynamically opens a tab at a lower `div` with the content for that option. Content is loaded with `load()` of Jquery in the container `div`.You can see in the picture below:

The first problem was that in the HTML loaded in each tab could not use the js file initially loaded in the index.html, as you can see in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/o7610t24/10/) you should check out a notice when we click the content of each tab, but does nothing .

The solution to this problem was included in each HTML code to load the appropriate script, and it worked properly. But to do it this way, if two HTML carry the same js, when one of the contents some event runs is repetite many times as tabs we have created, that is, if I open two different options (each in its own tab both charge the same js) by clicking on the first event associated performed twice, whereas if I do it in the second only done once. In short, whenever a function of a js used, is repeated as many times as there are dynamically loaded on the tabs.

And I tried `event.preventDefault();`or`event.stopPropagation();` and it does not solve the problem.

Would it be okay that it js is included twice in the overall structure of HTML? (Included in the initial head and then the container div)

Answer (score 3):

Dynamically loading HTML + JavaScript is not the best approach for this case. I suggest that you use some JavaScript SPA framework, like [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) or [ReactJS](https://facebook.github.io/react/). Both are very big and well supported projects, so you can find tons of documentation and tutorials. You'll most likely end up using Symfony only as a RESTful service and Angular/React taking care of the rest (template loading, sending request to server, etc). Also, js frameworks will take care of deep linking and in the end you'll have a better working, easier to maintain application.

It is a bit more work initially, especially until you bootstrap the application, but then it gets easier to maintain and implement new functionality, so it pays off in the end. With your current approach you soon will find yourself in a big mess full of 100s of templates, js callbacks, inclusions, etc. I'm saying this from a personal experience!

Answer (score 0):

Well...
Jquery works like this: when you attach an event to html, if the html does not exist, the event is attached to nothing. If the element exists then the event is correctly attached. It attaches only to existing elements when the on function is execute. That is a correct behaviour. In the past it used to exist a .live method that did exactly what you want: you attached an event and if you create the element after the attachment, the new element also contained the event.

Adding the js twice is not the solution. As you said after a click the button will be executed twice.
Why do not attach the events after loading the content? If you load it in the page start you can do in the main file:

```
$(function(){    // will force to execute the on method after all the page is loaded.
    $('.submenu .button').on ('click', function (){
         ...
    });
});
```

If you load the menu by ajax, in the callback and after adding the html menu to the main you must use the code I wrote above.

Comment: Hello @nicokiva,  I've read the documentation of the event `.live ()`which was updated by the event `.on ()` which is what I used in my code. The problem is that as html are dynamically loaded can not load the js after and I can not be able to use the added js above. I did not understand very well is added to the first `$ (function () {});` in your example. I added that in front of an event in my example and still not working. Excuse me but I am new to this and need to solve this problem.

Comment: Hi @nicokiva, I have continued to seek information to solve the problem of duplication events and I've seen that in order to use the added js on the homepage should use the following structure for events (delegate event handling): `$('#parent').on('click', '#child', function() { // Code });` or `$(document).on('click', '#selector', function() { // Code });` Effectively with this structure dynamically added html recognizes the functions without adding yet gains initially js again js. But the problem of duplicate events persists. It is repeated as many times as html have been loaded dynamically.